# Expo: Issue Sdk33 relating to expo-Constants

Tags: react-native, constants, expo

I have a message which I can't remove when running my application

> The following APIs have moved to separate packages and importing them from the "expo" package is deprecated: Constants.
>
> 1. Add correct versions of these packages to your project using:
>
>    expo install expo-constants
>
>    If "install" is not recognized as an expo command, update your
>      expo-cli installation.
> 2. Change your imports so they use specific packages instead of the "expo" package:
>
>    - import { Constants } from 'expo' -> import Constants from 'expo-constants'

I have installed the "expo-constants": "^5.0.1" in my package.json

Inside the code already set as

> import Constants from 'expo-constants'

Don't know why still having this message in my terminal when loading my application

Comment: Is it registered properly in the node_module folder?

Comment: What do u mean.. I run the application and is fine though

Comment: Had the same issue af upgrading, upgrading the CLI from `2.7.1` to `2.21.1` fixed it for me

Comment: Update: It came back after switching branches, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I also just updated to expo sdk33 and followed their directions to import Constants correctly, and I still also get the message. I believe this is not a sign that there's something wrong with your codebase but, instead, just a reminder they will have showing for a little while to make sure people see it and make the changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility that a third-party module is still using the deprecated expo constants. As soon as you update to expo 34, you will know. That was happening to me. When this becomes a problem, just upgrade that module.